# Get result from stdout

Tags: c++

To contextualize, I've been a developer for several years, but this is the first time I've worked on a C++ project.
I must "simply" create an executable which must, according to the parameters:

- either launch an application (and check that a process does not already exist)
- or pass all the parameters to another executable and display the output result.

Here is what i did :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool webCall;
    webCall= false;
    
    string exec = argv[0];
    exec.resize(exec.size() - 8); # oapp.exe (this one) and oapp.bck.exe are in same folder
    
    string parameters;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
        if (string(argv[i]) == "https://xxx.fr/createProjectFromFile") {
            webCall = true;
        }
        if (i  > 0)  {
            parameters += " " + string(argv[i]);
        }
    };

    exec += "oapp.bck.exe";
    ifstream fileExec;
    fileExec.open(exec);

    if (fileExec and !webCall) { // Redirect to oapp.bck.exe
        
        ofstream fileO;
        fileO.open("C:/Temp/test.log");
        fileO << exec + parameters;
        fileO.close();

        const char* command = string(exec+parameters).c_str();
        
        char buf[1000];
        FILE* output = popen(command, "r");
        while (fgets(buf, 1000, output)) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", buf);
        }
        pclose(output);

    }else{

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

There is an application that calls oapp.exe but it does not seem to work, this one does not seem to have the return of the launched command.

Comment: Why do you `fileExec.open(exec);`? (same as  `fileExec.open("oapp.bck.exe");`? There is no need to open the executable file (and you wouldn't do it in text-mode to begin with). All you need is the executable name and you then add the arguments (either to that string or concatenate as you have in `const char* command = string(exec+parameters).c_str();` The only file stream you need is `output` to read from the pipe. The `string exec = argv[0];` looks like it should use `argv[1]` -- unless the intent is to recursively call this executable again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues that look like misconceptions about how to put the pieces together to use `popen()` to execute a command allowing you to read the output from the command.

Populating `exec` with `argv[0]` adds the name of the CURRENTLY running program as the program to run with `popen()`. This does not seem likely. (while possible if you wanted mot make a recursive call, there are no `exit` conditions to stop the recursions. It looks like you intended to initialize `exed` with `argv[1]` (the first command line argument that can provide the name of the program you want to run in `popen()`.

Further down you have `exec += "oapp.bck.exe";` which would append `"oapp.bck.exe"` to the name of the currently running program in `exec`. If your intent is to have `oapp.bck.exe` be the program to run in `popen()`, just just initialize `string exec {"oapp.bck.exe"};`

Then next `parameters += " " + string(argv[i]);` seems to store what I would envision as the program name to run in `parameters.

So finally you concatenate `exec+parameters` in `command` which would result in a string containing `"CurrentlyRunningProgNameoapp.bck.exe whatever_from_argv[1]"` (you should output `command` and make sure it contains what you think it does. It looks like this is the area where the train is falling off the tracks.

Opening `exec` with `fileExec.open(exec);` makes no sense. That variable is unlikely to hold a readable file at this point, and if it was an executable file, you have just opening a binary file in text-mode -- not going to help.

So it looks like you are confused on what to send to `popen()`. It will be an executable followed by any arguments you want to pass to it.

**A Short Example on popen() Use**

Just to provide an example that will show the use of `popen()` you can adapt to what you are doing could simply be a program where you pass the exe name and any arguments to it and create your `command` sting in format:

```
    "some_program [arg1 arg2 arg3 ...]"
```

Where the args shown in `[ ... ]` can be options arguments to provide to `some_program` to call all at once in `popen()` For the short example we will do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2) {   /* validate at least one-argument for executable given */
    std::cerr << "error: insufficient number of arguemnts.\n"
                 "usage: " << argv[0] << " exe-to-run [arg1 arg2 ...]\n";
    return 1;
  }
  
  string command {argv[1]};                   /* append all arguments */
  for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    command += " ";
    command += argv[i];
  }
  
  char buf[1000];
  FILE* output = popen (exec.c_str(), "r");   /* call popen on c_str() */
  
  while (fgets(buf, 1000, output)) {          /* read each line of output */
      std::cout << buf;                       /* output to stdout */
  }
  
  pclose (output);
}
```

The program will take the executable to run and any arguments and pass them to `popen()`, e.g.

To get all the files beginning with `'w'` in Linux, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/popenexe ls -al "w*"
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  120 Jan 30 02:35 week2assignment.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  798 Apr 12  2020 whatprint.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  288 Mar 22  2021 windowtext.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1732 Apr 27 01:02 word_game_color.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 4513 Apr 30 02:01 word_game_color2.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 4942 Apr 28 16:54 word_game_color3.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2282 Oct 10  2019 wordcount.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  864 Dec 11 20:01 wordcount_map.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 4422 Mar 20  2018 wordlenfreq.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2417 Jun  9  2019 words_count_rev.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2252 Jun  9  2019 words_reverse.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2549 Jun  9  2019 words_reverse_no_punc.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1273 Jun  9  2019 words_reverse_rm_punc.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2768 Jun  9  2019 words_reverse_w_punc.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 3107 Jul 26  2020 workerhours.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1492 Jul 26  2020 workerhours_cstdio.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2310 Jul 26  2020 workerhours_cstdio_map.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 2088 Jul 26  2020 workerhours_cstdio_umap.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 3013 Jul 26  2020 workerhours_map.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1759 Jul 26  2020 workerhours_tst.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 3038 Jul 26  2020 workerhours_umap.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1019 Jul 26  2020 workershours_cstdio.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1195 Apr 18  2019 write-file.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1039 Feb 27  2021 wronggetline.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  576 May 23  2019 wrte.txt
```

On windows you could pass the `dir` command and any options you like, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/popenexe dir "w*"
week2assignment.txt   words_count_rev.cpp          workerhours_map.cpp
whatprint.cpp         words_reverse.cpp            workerhours_tst.cpp
windowtext.cpp        words_reverse_no_punc.cpp    workerhours_umap.cpp
word_game_color.cpp   words_reverse_rm_punc.cpp    workershours_cstdio.cpp
word_game_color2.cpp  words_reverse_w_punc.cpp     write-file.cpp
word_game_color3.cpp  workerhours.cpp              wronggetline.cpp
wordcount.cpp         workerhours_cstdio.cpp       wrte.txt
wordcount_map.cpp     workerhours_cstdio_map.cpp
wordlenfreq.cpp       workerhours_cstdio_umap.cpp
```

Which just prints the same files in a different format.

Look at how `popen()` and the strings being passed to `popen()` are being constructed. If you have further questions, drop a comment below.